# How to send a single file to multiple host using spring integration or using outbound channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, sftp, spring-integration

I have a scenario in which I need to send a text file from a host machine to multiple remote machines through SFTP and spring integration. Please suggest approach to achieve this. I'm able to send single file to single host using outbound channel adapter.
I have checked following links to create channel and session factory dynamically but I'm not able to create channel adapter programmatically please suggest
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/a93ee7fb35913de603dcca9970fea28bcfe956cf/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/ftp/DynamicFtpChannelResolverTests.java#L9

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/ftp/DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java

Answer (score 1):

Comes to mind the solution with `<publish-subscribe-channel>` and several `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` for each remove host.

You eve can configure the `<publish-subscribe-channel>` with `executor` to send to each subscriber concurrently.

And you will have an ability to continue to send only the message to the channel.

Comment: Request you to please elaborate more or some sample of the same as we are new to Spring Batch/Integration or some link which I can refer to.

Comment: First of all I suggest you to read EIP Book (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) and, of course SI Manual. The sample should be very simple, when you provide the same `<publish-subscribe-channel>` as an `input-channel` for your several `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>`s.